# Is there a word for the belief that everything is possible?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Either a word for belief itself or to describe a person who believes that any task is possible often in an irrational way.

Comment: Merely possible (by someone), or that the person believes that **they themselves** can do any task?

Comment: "Dead" comes to mind.

Comment: Over-optimistic. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/over-optimistic

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well as I stated above 'a person who believes that any task is possible.' This applies to them as well as to others. To think others "can't" do something would contradict their own belief. ;)

Comment: Sort of megalomania? a  psychopathological condition characterized by delusional fantasies of wealth, power, or omnipotence.

Comment: Well I suppose theoretically any task is possible. But some (most?) have a probability of success which is so close to zero as might be indistinguishable.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That point is not subject to my question. I'm thinking of a person who believes any conceivable idea of a human-brain can be a reality. It might be humans flying, pigs living in houses, To them from any ridiculous to most fantastical idea is possible.

Comment: You might be looking for *metaphysical belief* or a less common term *metaphysicism*. Although, "anything is possible" notion can be part of metaphysics itself.

Comment: It's possible there is such a word.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps gullible, over-credulous, or hopelessly naive?

[**gullible**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gullible):

> Easily persuaded to believe something; credulous

[**credulous**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/credulous):

> Having or showing too great a readiness to believe things

[**naive**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/naive):

> showing a lack of experience, wisdom, or judgement

It doesn't quite convey the idea that the person believes that *everything is possible*, though. Merely this person's inclination to *believe* that they are.

So perhaps combine this with something that connotes optimism or lack of realism -- e.g. (overconfident and) **gullible optimist**.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I was hoping for a more philosophical term. 'Pollyannic' was mentioned by someone, I liked the term, but it wasn't the most felicitous given the context.

Answer (score 1):

Sanguine - 
"Anticipating the best; optimistic; not despondent; confident; full of hope."

Source; Wiktionary http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sanguine

Comment: Sanguine is a synonym for optimistic. No I wasn't looking for this term. You can read my comment in Centaurus's answer.

Comment: Andy: I would argue that 'sanguine' is not a precise synonym of 'optimistic' as it refers to one of the 'Four Temperaments' (which are analogous to the classical Four Elements) from which all other states of mind are mythologically derived. It therefore has the connotation of being 'primal', 'basic' or 'elemental' optimism or confidence.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation of the term, but they all sound a little too euphemistic to describe someone of an irrational disposition. Does the term 'sanguine' have the connotation of believing in something irrational? If it does I'd take it as the answer  to my question.

Comment: Not as is, no. Depending on context, someone who referred to themselves as being sanguine as opposed to confident _because_ they believed in Alchemical principles would be a little wacky. TBF, the original question didn't request an implication of irrationality, just a term for super confidence. With out resorting to phrases, neologisms and prefixes, like 'omni-confident' and 'ultra-optimistic', I don't think you're going to find a suitable term.

Comment: There probably should be a word, given that I personally have met several people who are close to matching this description.

Comment: Ah you've met some gems then. :) Do let me know when you come across a suitable enough term to describe their character.

Comment: Without wishing to get too clinical, I usually settle for 'deranged', 'delusional', 'batty', 'away with the fairies' (a term used by an ex-girlfriend to describe herself at certain times) and, occasionally, 'psychopathic'.

Comment: Well your ex really had proclivity for supernatural. :) I like all those terms, I posted in some other comment I was going to settle with deranged to describe this person and fantastical for belief.

Comment: 'Fantastical' is a good word, I don't have nearly enough occasion to use it.

Comment: Well you could say - My ex used to gossip fantastical ideas with her fairies. :)

Comment: I got the impression that she mostly used to jump around, wave her arms in the air and go 'Whee! Whee!' It was kinda cute but it got old fairly quickly.

Comment: Yeah, I think she should have modified her rituals from time to time, instead of being married to the monotonous. :)

Answer (score 0):

What popped into my head were "hopeless optimist" and "naive idealist". Googling this, you find a blog entitled "Hopelessly Optimistic Naive Idealist"!

Clearly the concept is regarded as humorous.

Answer (score 0):

> Pollyannic

This describes someone who believes positively in things even irrationally in the face contradicting evidence.

Comment: I had to look up this term. This is what I read The Pollyanna principle is the tendency for people to remember pleasant items more accurately than unpleasant ones. I'm afraid it's a little of place to describe the person in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found the right term. It's called **Quixotic** - Having or showing ideas or plans that are imaginative but usually not practical. :)
Origin - From the character Don Quixote in the novel by Miguel de Cervantes, whose adventures are a result of him trying to achieve or obtain things that are impossible. Meanwhile, Thanks for for all the answers. I appreciate everyone's efforts to get me close to what I was looking for.

Comment: If this is the answer, then a better question would have been someone whose primary characteristic is being irrationally/unrealistically idealistic. That's very different than believing every task is possible.

Comment: @JimReynolds I know I didn't phrase my question in the best way possible, but I did mention the words irrational and believing in every possibility.

Comment: Well, that's ok, of course. I'm curious what led you to start thinking about the question. Is it something you can share?

Comment: @JimReynolds Nothing in particular, it was just a curious thought. I'm always looking for philosophical terms relating to human nature. :)

Comment: Ah, cool. Me too. How did you find *quixotic?*

Comment: Well I'm reading this novel Europe - A History by Norman Davies. I posted this question yesterday and I found the word Quixotic this afternoon, reading midway through the novel. :) I can't believe my luck sometimes. It was used to describe Columbus as a Quixotic Jew who ventured into the New World in search of the lost tribes of Israel lol

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question as posted: **"Is there a word for the belief that everything is possible?"**

If someone thinks he is **endowed with omnipotence**, he thinks he can do anything, he thinks he is **omnipotent** (adj). And if **He** can really do anything, **He is omnipotent**.

> - having unlimited or universal power, authority, or force; all-powerful. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/omnipotence)
> - having complete or unlimited power. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omnipotent)

**omnipotence** is the noun.  "Some people question God's omnipotence."

Comment: I'm inclined to think this person as deranged and their belief as fantastical. :) Omnipotence is the term I would have been looking for before asking the question. On first notice Omnipotence/Omnipotent sounded like they could only be applied to supernatural entities. I don't want the term to imply that. Still I thought better of the terms with your examples. Perhaps it's still not the ideal, 'established' term for someone of the said belief or the belief itself,  but so far this is the closest I've come to. I think a more humourous term would be felicitous here, hence Deranged, Fantastical.

Answer (score -1):

I would consider them to be [idealistic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idealistic)

> adjective
>
> 1. of or relating to idealism or idealists.

where ideal is defined as

> noun
>
> 1. a conception of something in its perfection.

Related would be [idealism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idealism) (emphasis mine)

> The tendency to represent things in an ideal form, or as they might or should be rather than as they are, **with emphasis on values**.

(from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/))